# How to position drawable start icon at the start of the material text input layout

Tags: android, kotlin, android-drawable, android-textinputlayout, android-textinputedittext

How to position the drawable start icon at the start of text input layout

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="New Password"
                    app:expandedHintEnabled="true"
                    app:hintTextAppearance="@style/text_medium_12_size"
                    app:errorTextAppearance="@style/text_regular_10_size"
                    app:boxStrokeColor="@color/main_theme_color"
                    app:startIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_baseline_lock"
                    style="@style/Widget.Design.TextInputLayout">

                    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:paddingStart="0dp"
                        android:paddingEnd="0dp"
                        android:drawablePadding="0dp"
                        style="@style/text_medium_12_size"
                        android:importantForAutofill="no"/>

                </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

The result of the above code is show in image below

[image]

But I want to achieve like the drawable start icon at start of the text input layout start which is show as image attched below

[image]

I need to remove the extra start space between drawable start icon of the text input layout. Is is possible to achieve it?

Comment: you can use `drawablePadding` to get the space between icon and text

Comment: I need to remove the start space of ``` app:startIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_baseline_lock" ```. setting drawable padding not works for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove `app:startIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_baseline_lock"` in `TextInputLayout`

and add `android:drawableStart="@mipmap/ic_baseline_lock"` in `TextInputEditText`

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="New Password"
                    app:expandedHintEnabled="true"
                    app:hintTextAppearance="@style/text_medium_12_size"
                    app:errorTextAppearance="@style/text_regular_10_size"
                    app:boxStrokeColor="@color/main_theme_color"
                    app:startIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_baseline_lock" // remove this line
                    style="@style/Widget.Design.TextInputLayout">

                    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:paddingStart="0dp"
                        android:paddingEnd="0dp"
                        android:drawableStart="@mipmap/ic_baseline_lock" //add this line
                        android:drawablePadding="0dp"
                        style="@style/text_medium_12_size"
                        android:importantForAutofill="no"/>

                </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```